# SQL Workaround for avoiding multiple GROUP BY's

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, group-by

I have an SQL Query (on a PostgreSQL database) that recursively traverses a friendship table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE friendship(pID, distance, path) AS (
  (SELECT pID1, 1, CONCAT(getName(pID2), '->', getName(pID1)) 
FROM pkp_symmetric WHERE pID2 = 94)
UNION
  (SELECT sym.pID1, distance + 1, CONCAT(path, '->', getName(sym.pID2)) 
   FROM pkp_symmetric sym JOIN friendship f ON sym.pID2 = f.pID WHERE distance < 5)
   )
SELECT getName(f.pID), min(f.distance), f.path
FROM friendship f 
WHERE f.pID <> 94
GROUP BY f.pID;
```

Where `getName(pID)` is just a helper function to print out the name instead of the `ID`'s.
This query will give an error, because `f.path` needs to be in a `GROUP BY`-Clause or in an aggregate function (SQL state: 42803). However I need this query to be just grouped by `f.pID` as stated. 
Is there a workaround to get `f.path` into the `select`, but without grouping it?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `f.path` -> `MAX(f.path)`?

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda this would work, but not give the expected result, since the friendship table holds the distance and the exact friendship path from the person with id 94 to any other person it is related to. So applying any aggregate function is not really an option i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (f.pId) getName(f.pID), f.distance, f.path
FROM friendship f 
WHERE f.pID <> 94
ORDER BY f.pID, f.distance
```